# C# How do I cast a Tuple via Unsafe.As?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, syntax, casting

I try to cast a Tuple to another with a generic type in. But it gives me an error.

Here's the code

```
public void Method<TEntityObject>()
{
    var collections = new Dictionary<Type, (int, List<object>)>();

    var requiredCollection =
        Unsafe.As<(int, List<TEntityObject>)>(collections[typeof(TEntityObject)]);
}
```

Here's the error

`Error    CS0452    The type '(int, List<TEntityObject>)' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Unsafe.As<T>(object?)'`

Comment: You might copy it to an array first. I don't think the memory footprint of a tuple is compatible. (sequential memory)

Comment: You could use `System.Tuple<int, List<TEntityObject>>` as the type parameter which would fix your error, but I'm not sure this would work anyway.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidG, but Tuple<int, List<TEntityType> isn't the same with (int, List<TEntityType>) so it throws me Error    CS0029    Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Tuple<int, System.Collections.Generic.List<TEntityObject>>' to '(int, System.Collections.Generic.List<TEntityObject>)', so it doesn't fit in my interface return type. Maybe I should change the interface.

Comment: I found in docs that syntax with brackets represent ValueTuple which is value type. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuples-vs-systemtuple

Comment: @DavidG Sounds pretty dangerous. `Unsafe.As` is meant for high-perf scenarios where you know the cast will work. But `Tuple<int, object>` is not `Tuple<int, List<TEntityType>>` so it's going to cause runtime issues even though `Unsafe.As` won't throw. It's called *Unsafe* for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the tuple item separately. The dictionary should be declared as `Dictionary<Type, (int, object)>` or maybe `Dictionary<Type, (int, IList)>`.

`Unsafe.As` is the wrong thing to use (only works with reference types, not `ValueTuple`), and in any case is meant for high-performance scenarios.

```cs
Dictionary<Type, (int, object)> collections = new();

public (int, List<TEntityObject>) GetIntAndList<TEntityObject>()
{
    var tuple = collections[typeof(TEntityObject)];
    return (tuple.Item1, (List<TEntityObject>)tuple.Item2);
}
```

If your lists are actually all stored as `List<object>` then you have to either return that, or use `ToList` to create a new list.

```
public (int, IReadOnlyList<TEntityObject>) GetIntAndList<TEntityObject>()
{
    var tuple = collections[typeof(TEntityObject)];
    return (tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2.OfType<TEntityObject>().ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that it's unsafe, but my case was meant to be with high performance. Your answer don't solve my issue in the way I've seen (it's probably impossible so I've changed the architecture a bit) it but I will flag your answer as a solution.

Comment: The cost of a single cast is miniscule (it's a single branch instruction) so I'm not sure if you've really got the right idea when it comes to "high-performance". This sort of thing would primarily be done in cases where the cast would be done millions of times *per second* at the very least. The code in your question is very contrived, so it's hard to answer exactly what you need.

Comment: It needs to be used in the Data Access Layer.

Comment: Even less of a reason to worry about the performance of a single cast, when the main concern is the performance of the database.